# RestTemplate 404 error upon adding HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory

Tags: java, httpclient, resttemplate, requestfactory

I am using RestTemplate exchange method to call a Microservice.
Its working fine with the below code.

```
RestTemplate rs = new RestTemplate();
rs.exchange(........);
```

But if I add HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory to the resttemplate, its giving 404 Not found exception with the below code

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setMaxConnTotal(200).setMaxConnPerRoute(100).build();
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));

restTemplate.exchange(......);
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this without removing HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory?